# Puzzled with getting "Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference exception"

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

It seems a simple code block and I believe I understand what the "Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference exception" means, but I cannot figure out why I am getting it. I seem to be checking everything before reaching this line where the exception is thrown:

```
for (int a = 0; a < (ItemList[i].Count - BufferSize); a++)
```

ItemList is a dynamic list of lists (or two-dimensional list)

```
List<dynamic> ItemList = new List<dynamic>();
int BufferSize = 35;
```

Some code goes after this that populates ItemList
Then the block in question

```
for (var i = 0; i < ItemList.Count; i++)
{
    if (ItemList[i] != null)
    {
        if (ItemList[i].Count > BufferSize)
        {
            // this line throws exception
            for (int a = 0; a < (ItemList[i].Count - BufferSize); a++)
            {
                ItemList[i][a].Image = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: tag added, thanks for your reminder

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that can be null in that code is the element in the second array, ´ItemList[i][a]`.

You might want to reduce the nesting to make the code easier to read.

```
for (var i = 0; i < ItemList.Count; i++)
{
    if (ItemList[i] == null || ItemList[i].Count <= BufferSize)
    {
         continue;
    }

    for (int a = 0; a < (ItemList[i].Count - BufferSize); a++)
    {
         ItemList[i][a].Image = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but the exception seems being thrown before even reaching ItemList[i][a]